# how to display Highcharts from database in C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, highcharts

I have seen this http://codepedia.info/chartjs-asp-net-create-pie-chart-with-database-calling-jquery-ajax-c/ link and followed every steps but dint get the output(i have used "public class cityPopulation") in code behind instead of asmx page will it be the error

```
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function drawPieChart(seriesData) {

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Population percentage city wise'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Brands",
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: seriesData
                }]
            });
        }
        $("#btnCreatePieChart").on('click', function (e) {
            var pData = [];
            pData[0] = $("#ddlyear").val();

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ pData: pData });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "aspchartjsdemo.aspx/getCityPopulation",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess_,
                error: OnErrorCall_
            });

            function OnSuccess_(response) {
                var aData = response.d;
                var arr = []

                $.map(aData, function (item, index) {
                    var i = [item.city_name, item.population];
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.name = item.city_name;
                    obj.y = item.population;
                    arr.push(obj);
                });
                var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
                var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));

                drawPieChart(jsonArray);

            }
            function OnErrorCall_(response) {
                alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyear" runat="server" >
            <asp:ListItem>2010</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Button ID="btnCreatePieChart" runat="server" Text="Button" />

<br />
<div>
    <div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


here is my  Code Behind..Im Unable to Fetch the data from database.

    [WebMethod]
    public List<cityPopulation> getCityPopulation(List<string> pData)
    {
        List<cityPopulation> p = new List<cityPopulation>();

        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=Localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=database4;"))
        {
            string myQuery = "SELECT id_, city_name, population FROM  tb_city_population WHERE  year_of = @year";
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = myQuery;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", pData[0]);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    cityPopulation cpData = new cityPopulation();
                    cpData.city_name = dr["city_name"].ToString();
                    cpData.population = Convert.ToInt32(dr["population"].ToString());
                    p.Add(cpData);
                }
            }
        }
        return p;
    }

    public class cityPopulation
    {
        public string city_name { get; set; }
        public int population { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
Any Help Highly appreciated..
```

Comment: The bugs here is usually bad javascript render, or bad data format. See first of all if you have javascript errors on your console. Then fix them and continue with debugging what data you send.

Comment: Hi Aristos thanks for ur reply..I have seen the console but no bugs were found.

Comment: then debug your data to see what you send and how you input it to hightchart

Comment: Even i have done debugging but the control in not moving to the ajax call

Comment: How your JSON data does it look like ?

Comment: Hi Sebastian .. Actually im using fetching data from database and trying to convert it to json using ajax call but nothing works

Comment: So what your aspchartjsdemo.aspx/getCityPopulation url returns or how your response does it look like ?

Comment: Try to write the contents of `jsonArray` to a textbox or something. Then it becomes much easier to see how the JSON looks. Then compare it to my example and fix the differences.

Comment: My Json luks like this:.   { "type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } }, "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "WRD_ID": "W001", "WRD_NO": 1, "WRD_AREA": 2.13370891287, "TIME_ST": "2015\/09\/22" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 81.924602345391904, 16.883873211394874 ], [ 81.924731978090534, 16.884286038788275 ],

Comment: This link i have followed .. so can any one please tell me where i have gone wrong ..im using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

This is how I build the Pie:

```
<div id="pieChart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>

<script>
    var myPieData = [ ['AAA', 34.03], ['BBB', 27.01], ['CCC', 18.77], ['DDD', 11.01], ['EEE', 5.91], ['FFF', 3.27] ];

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'pieChart',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'My PieData'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 2
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: false,
                cursor: 'default',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: '',
            data: myPieData
        }]
    });
</script>
```

The part you have to replace with your own data is `[ ['Label A', 34.03], ['Label B', 27.01], ['Label C', 18.77], ['Label D', 11.01], ['Label E', 5.91], ['Label F', 3.27] ]`
Of course the total value of all the data should be 100.00%

You can do that with a Literal or a string that is filled with content from code behind: `var myPieData = [ <%= pieData %> ]` or get it from an external source.

Depending on your localization settings, a numeric value can contain a "," instead of a "." (23,59 or 23.59). If your localization uses a "," you will have to replace that with a dot.

**UPDATE**

As requested an example of how to get a correct string that you can use to build the pie. This should get you started... Just make sure that `population` is in percentages, not absolute numbers.

```
public string getCityPopulation(List<string> pData)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string myQuery = "SELECT city_name, population FROM tb_city_population WHERE (year_of = @year)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", pData[0]);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append("[");
                    sb.Append("'" + dr["city_name"].ToString() + "'");
                    sb.Append(", ");
                    sb.Append(dr["population"].ToString().Replace(",", "."));
                    sb.Append("],");
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //error connecting\reading the database
        }
    }

    return "[ " + sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',') + " ]";
}
```

Comment: Hi VDWWD thanks for your reply..Actually im getting data from database and converting it to json. If any Example will be highly appriciated

Comment: Thanks VDWWD your code i think working fine but when i click the button as done in this tutorial [link](http://codepedia.info/highcharts-asp-net-create-pie-chart-with-jquery-ajax-in-c-sharp-ms-sql-database/) . There is no output .Can u please guide me where is going wrong , Thanks alor for ur help

Comment: Try to break up your problem into little pieces first. Start with making a page that the Ajax function calls to. When the call is made to that page it should only output a single string (no HTML etc). Then make sure that the string has the output like in my example by calling `getCityPopulation` and Response.Write the result. You can test that by opening that page in the browser. If that is successful try to get the Ajax call working from the Main page.

Comment: Thanks VDWWD for ur support ..I have found where  i was going wrong